# How can I use part of the JSON response to fetch certain outputs in the same JSON?

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use JQ to parse the values from the **compare** list (.query.compare[]) and the results. Getting the results has been an issue as the key values are the same parameters as the values in the **compare** list.

How do I use the values from the compare list to perform a match that can be used to extract the values from the respective keys in the **results** section?

```
{
  "query": {
    "unit": "km",
    "code": "10005",
    "country": "us",
    "compare": [
      "10006",
      "10007"
    ]
  },
  "results": {
    "10006": 0.54,
    "10007": 0.93
  }
}
```

Based on the JSON above, I should be able to get the **compare** list values (10006, 10007) and **results** (0.54, 0.93) separately

Comment: i don't know if jq can do that. You might just have to script it. Save the json to a file, then use jq to get the compare values, parse it into an array and iterate, then use jq to get the results

Comment: What about saving the compare values to a variable name and then using that to match with the results keys? I think this works but what I've tried so far hasn't given me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.query.compare` array to select from `.results` like this:

```bash
$ cat example.json | jq '.results[.query.compare[]]'
0.54
0.93
```

To show the compare and results separately, we can use the syntax from above:

```bash
$ cat example.json | jq '{compare: .query.compare, results: [.results[.query.compare[]]]}'
{
  "compare": [
    "10006",
    "10007"
  ],
  "results": [
    0.54,
    0.93
  ]
}
```

(I saved the json given in the question in example.json)